# css for modal - how to position it above page yet scrollable in window

Tags: html, css

Here is the html:

```
<body>
 <div class="ngdialog">
   <div class="ngdialog-overlay></div>
   <div class="ngdialog-content>
      ...modal content
   </div.
 </div>
<body>
```

The ngdialog div is, as you can guess, an modal (z-index: 10000).
My goal is, by applying some comination of styles (position, float etc.) to the elements to make it so that:

a) When the modal is displayed, have the overlay (grey and opacity; 0.5) cover all other elements in the page.

b) If the modal content is longer than the page, I would like the user to be able to use the main scroll bar to see the bottom/top of the modal. In other words, if the rest of the page is only 100px but the modal is 200px, I would like the scoll bar to allow the user to scroll that extra 100px.

The issue I am having is that when I position ngdialog as absolute, the window won't allow me to scroll to see the rest of the modal (as the absolute element is no longer in the standard element flow).

If I try to use fixed positioning, there is no scroll bar. If I use relative positioning, the other page elements (which the overlay is above) get moved around.

I have tried (what feels like) every combination of absolute, relative, fixed, static, float on all of these elements and I can't get the behavior I am seeking.

Keep in mind that body is position: relative (this can be changed if need be).

Thanks in advance, appreciate all comments.

Edit: Sorry, I had to go to sleep there, here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/vpgoy756/1/

Comment: Have you tried messing with the `overflow` property?

Comment: yes, I played with overflow as well. I mean perhaps I am missing "the standard modal styling"?

Comment: Do you have a fiddle I can mess with? I can't replicate your problem: https://jsfiddle.net/LB__/sL88jpet/

Comment: yeah, I will try to post a fiddle

Comment: @LB-- I posted the fiddle, thanks.

Comment: are you willing to accept double-scrollbars when the page content and dialog both exceed the page height? https://jsfiddle.net/LB__/vpgoy756/2/

Comment: Looks good, I will try it in the actual webpage and report back.

Comment: @LB-- looks good, obviously I would rather have one scrollbar but I have put enough time into it at this point and at least this is functioning. You want to post an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WIthout changing your HTML structure, this is what you'd need to do:

```css
* {
    /* This was to save typing */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.ngdialog {
    z-index: 10000;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ngdialog-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, .4);
}
.ngdialog-content {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.panel {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    min-height: 500px;
    z-index: 10000;
}
.reg-page-block {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- ^ from your provided fiddle -->
<body>
    <div class="ngdialog">
        <div class="ngdialog-overlay"></div>
        <div class="ngdialog-content">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">modal</div>
                <div class="panel-body">content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="reg-page-block">Regular Page</div>
</body>
```

Be aware that if both the dialog and content are taller than the viewport, you will get double scrollbars - this may not be desirable but you specifically asked for the dialog to scroll separately from the content.

Answer (score 0):

Try some of this CSS and see if it does the trick. It's hard to provide an exact solution without seeing your current CSS code, but maybe this will work.

Use this HTML structure instead:

```
<div class="ngdialog-overlay">
    <div class="ngdialog-content">CONTENT HERE</div>
</div>
```

And this CSS code:

```
.ngdialog-overlay {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#333333;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index:10000;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.ngdialog-content{
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding-top:30px;
    padding-bottom:30px;

    /* Optional if you want content vertically centered */
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The trick is **overflow:scroll;** and **height:100%;** - because we have a set height, if the contents become any taller than that they will overflow and scroll. But in this case, when the user tries to scroll it will actually be scrolling the **.ngdialog-overlay** element and not the window itself.

http://jsfiddle.net/bcole808/6wcsxf3z/1/

Comment: I think the situation may be closer to https://jsfiddle.net/LB__/sL88jpet/ but I am awaiting a response from the OP.

Comment: My CSS achieves the same effect as well (example: [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bcole808/6wcsxf3z/1/) ) but in my implementation the other elements on the page will remain in the same position while the modal above the main content will appear to "scroll" on its own.

Comment: When the page content is long enough you get double scrollbars, which probably isn't desirable.

Comment: @BenCole My content is not in my overlay. I don't have a choice in the matter. As the name suggests, these elements are being generated by an outside angular directive ng-dialog. I can't rearrange the elements. I must achieve the outcome using styles alone.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS file Add below lines

```
.modal-dialog {
  transform: translateY(50%)!important;
}
```

You can change 50% to any other value which will solve problem in your Browser
It worked for me